# The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again. Magento 2.4.0

Tags: php, mysql, linux, magento, magento2

I installed magento 2.4.0 on my Linux server from godaddy. I'm unable to add the products to it. It is showing the Error is `The stock item was unable to be saved. Please try again.` Can any one help me from this please[image]

Comment: Check this out https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/The-stock-item-was-unable-to-be-saved-Please-try-again/td-p/449973

Comment: I tried it but still, it's not working. Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 41):

Please change all indexer as **Update by Schedule** mode in `system-> index management`. It's working for me.

Comment: Thank you brother, You are my heroo

Comment: Hi, I had already set to schedule, but it kept giving me the error. I changed on save and the error disappeared, but I also changed the database user permissions from "usage" to "ALL" and changed two products without getting the error.

Comment: This was great resonse

Answer (score 20):

If you are using **Elasticsearch** instead of **Mysql**. then please check once that elasticsearch is working or not.

```
sudo service elasticsearch status    // for checking the Running Status
sudo service elasticsearch start    // for Start
sudo service elasticsearch restart    // for Restart
```

Comment: yes, elastic search has to be up and running

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed it. There was an entry missing in cataloginventory_stock

**try to run this query**

```
INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock (stock_id, website_id, stock_name) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default');
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Magento 2.4.2 installation location:

```
cd /var/www/html
```

Flush cache

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Chek Indexer Status

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

Reset Indexer

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Reindex Indexer

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Chek Indexer Status

```
php bin/magento indexer:status
```

Chek indexer Info

```
php bin/magento indexer:info
```

Finally Flush Cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Restart
sudo reboot

---

Login to admin and check

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Elastic search service active status ?

```
service elasticsearch status
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I just had to execute:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to use Opensearch instead of Elasticsearch.
There is an option in the backend for that, by default elastic is selected.

Go to Magento Admin then,

Stores > Configurations > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search

[Admin search engine backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWLYQ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Tested in Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1.
Please make sure Elastic Search is running using the  command

```
sudo service elasticsearch status
```

If it is not running start elastic search using command

```
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Answer (score 0):

I've Migrated the magento 2.3.x into 2.4.x. I faced the same issues.
I've resolved this issue the following way.

1. INSERT INTO cataloginventory_stock (stock_id, website_id, stock_name) VALUES ('1', '1', 'default');
2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
3. php bin/magento cache:flush

But still i am facing the same issue, then I did the below steps.

1. mysqldump --single-transaction -u root -p mydb --triggers | sed -e 's/DEFINER[ ]*=[ ]*[^*]**/*/' > mydb_without_definer.sql
2. DROP DATABASE `mydb`;
3. create DATABASE `mydb`;
4. mysql -u root -p mydb < mydb_without_definer.sql
5. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
6. php bin/magento cache:flush

Thank you!
Pilathraj

Answer (score 0):

On **Magento 2.4.6**, which now uses OpenSearch instead of Elastisearch

I was having this problem until I added the following to the end of
`/etc/opensearch/opensearch.yml`

```
plugins.security.disabled: true
```

Remember to restart OpenSearch after the edit.  On my system this was
`systemctl restart opensearch`

I am running both Magento2 and OpenSearch on a single server.  OpenSearch is listening on `localhost:9200`; which I can secure through IPTABLES.  I suspect that configuring OpenSearch's TLS settings correctly would also work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using elastic search and you are using opensearch

Please configure opensearch from

Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search > Search Engine